# Wrapping a parentheses in a PHP string with an extra div

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a string like this:

`$string = "Track Length (trackLengthFT)"`

I want to convert the string to:

`$string = "Track Length <div class="parenthesis">(trackLengthFT)</div>"`

Comment: So what exactly have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following to convert anything inside parentheses with that.
Following code will do this for you using regex.

```
$string = preg_replace('/(.*?)(?:\()(.*?)(?:\))/', '$1<div class="parenthesis">($2)</div>', $search);
```

Comment: If you have a problem and you use regex to fix it, usually you have two problems. :)

Comment: Regex is typically used for validation and parsing. If he were to just use this to statically parse his website for parenthesis and output this to those static entrys or db entrys then I would say he's fine. But to run this dynamically yeah you got a point.

Comment: That looks overly complex. Why not just replace the part in question, eg `preg_replace('/\(.+?\)/', '<div class="parenthesis">$0</div>', $string)`

Comment: Phil he could do that if he wanted to try, '(\(.+?\))' and <div class="parenthesis">$1</div> for it to work properly. As @Phil suggested you can do it that way here is a live example of it. http://regexr.com/3e63e

Comment: What do you mean *"work properly"*? There's no need for the extra parentheses and `$0` is the entire match so it works just fine

Comment: Just use @Phil's solution

Comment: I'm not sure why the comment got corrected but you did not use grouping. I was using grouping that's all.

Comment: @JQluv there's no need to use grouping. The comment edit was because I forgot to add the last `$string` arg to `preg_replace`

Answer (score 1):

Provided you don't need to support nested parentheses, eg

> *"Track Length (trackLengthFT (45 mins))*"

matching a non-empty string in parentheses is as easy as `/\(.+?\)/`. The [lazy repeater](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) `.+?` tells the wildcard to stop at the first ")" instead of the last. You can then search for these patterns and replace them with the wrapped version

```
$string = preg_replace('/\(.+?\)/', '<div class="parenthesis">$0</div>', $string);
```

`$0` in the replacement string refers to the whole string matched by the regular expression.

Demo ~ https://eval.in/636450

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit verbose and perhaps easier to read for some, rather than regular expressions, This is not very flexible as it will only wrap the last item from a sentence.

```
$string = "Track Length (trackLengthFT)";
$a_string = explode(' ', $string);
$last = array_pop($a_string);
$div = sprintf('<div class="a-class">%s</div>', $last);
array_push($a_string, $div);
$final = implode(' ', $a_string); 
// Track Length <div class="a-class">(trackLengthFT)</div>
```

This is an alternative way to accomplish the same and making it reusable. This allows you wrap the last item that was `exploded` by `space` by any other function.

```
$wrap_in_div = function($content, $class) {
    return sprintf('<div class="%s">%s</div>', $class, $content);
  };

  $wrap_last_by_space = function($string) {
    $explode_string = explode(' ', $string);
    $last = array_pop($explode_string);
    return function($fn, $class) use ($explode_string, $last) {
      $explode_string[] =  call_user_func($fn, $last, $class);
      return implode(' ', $explode_string );
    };
  };


  $a = $wrap_last_by_space('Track Length (trackLengthFT)');
  $b = $a($wrap_in_div, 'parenthesis');

  var_dump($b);
```